# Is LinkedList breaks contract if amount of elements in list greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, size, contract

java doc for `java.util.List#size()`

> Returns the number of elements in this list. If this list contains
>   more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Research `java.util.LinkedList` source code:

public method:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    addBefore(e, header);
        return true;
    }
```

---

```
private Entry<E> addBefore(E e, Entry<E> entry) {
    Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(e, entry, entry.previous);
    newEntry.previous.next = newEntry;
    newEntry.next.previous = newEntry;
    size++;
    modCount++;
    return newEntry;
 }
```

Thus if before adding element size equals `Integer.MAX_VALUE` size will become 
`-Integer.MAX_VALUE-1`

method size just returns field value without checks:

```
 public int size() {
    return size;
 }
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score -1):

You will run out of memory long before you've managed to put over 2 billion objects inside the list, so there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Even then, you wouldn't keep a List that large in memory. It wouldn't be effective. But I promise that when you have a few terabytes of memory in your computer, that Java version will have upgraded the size() method to return a long :)

Comment: It is question about contract. not about effective.

Comment: Well, obviously it doesn't fulfill the contract. My opinion is that this is highly irrelevant for any fruitful programming. It will take years before that would be an issue.

Comment: looks like different versions of evolutions for LinkedList and List. I think that good solving - write in List java doc that it works only while size<Integer.MAX_VALUE , otherwise unpredictable behavior

Comment: I would imagine there are more important things to worry about in the JDK than this.

Comment: It is hidden future problem

Comment: No it's not. You're talking about lists with over 2 billion elements. If those become commonplace, we won't be writing Java anymore by then.

Comment: Don't you think that memory in future will so fast ?

Comment: You're assuming that memory size and speed will increase (which is true), but you're also assuming that everything else remains the same (which is false).